# Rspec + Capybara: How can I use expect to validate all items in a field?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Brothers help me please. I need to validate the values ​​of this combo, I tried it with a command I found here but I still haven't had success. The error I'm getting is: Reason:
Ambiguous match, found 7 elements matching visible option nil
----------------------------------------------
I noticed that the first value is white I don't know if this is the error but I tried to get it for a specific value and I couldn't do it either!!

My Code:

class Screen_Grupo_Intervencao < SitePrism::Page

include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods::ExpectHost
include RSpec::Matchers

element :estrutura, :xpath,             '//*[@name="_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY"]'

all(screen_grupo_intervencao.estrutura select)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfFQv.jpg).should have_text('CADASTRO TÉCNICO D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA ENGENHARIA GESTÃO DE PERDAS GSC COMERCIAL GSO OPERACIONAL')

```
<select style="padding-right:0px;width:100%;" class="f fA" onrealchange="return true;" onchange="setTooltip(this,'');realChangeListener(event);" id="686" name="_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY" tabindex="151" evidence="">
   <option title="" selected="" value="" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;"></option>
   <option title="" value="61" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;">CADASTRO TÉCNICO</option>
   <option title="" value="41" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;">D&amp;C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA</option>
   <option title="" value="62" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;">ENGENHARIA</option>
   <option title="" value="63" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;">GESTÃO DE PERDAS</option>
   <option title="" value="1" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;">GSC COMERCIAL</option>
   <option title="" value="21" class="f fA" style="border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:1em;box-shadow:none;">GSO OPERACIONAL</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be a big help if you read the Stackoverflow instructions on inserting code into questions so it would format it correctly.  Also the code you're showing somehow has a linked '1' stuck in the middle of it.

The error you're getting is because you have specified `element :estrutura, :xpath, '//*[@name="_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY"]'` which means there should be only 1 of them.  However on your page there are apparently 7 elements matching the xpath.  Either make the selector more specific so it only matches one thing, or change it to `elements :estrutura, :xpath, '//*[@name="_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY"]'` so it allows multiple elements to be found.

I would also suggest to stop using xpath when it's not necessary - `elements :estrutura, '[name="_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY"]'`

Assuming you are meant to have multiple matching elements on the page and I'm reading you're code right then I think you'd be doing

```
screen_grupo_intervencao.estrutura[1].should have_text('CADASTRO TÉCNICO D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA ENGENHARIA GESTÃO DE PERDAS GSC COMERCIAL GSO OPERACIONAL')
```

although that seems like a strange way to be testing.

Comment: I appreciate your help, you as always very friendly and humble in your observations. The world needs people just like you. Any mistake I make, I ask you to forgive me because I'm still learning... I'll test and study your changes... Regarding your comment that you think it's a strange way for me to test the items, it's because I want to validate the domain of these fields that must be fixed. If you have a suggestion I humbly accept it.

Comment: I confess that for me to get well I need to study a lot of technique to inspect the elements of the page, a fact that this is much simpler for developers and not automatists, who need to know this in depth.

Comment: @Tadeu. Using siteprism I believe it would be something like `expect(screen_grupo_intervencao.estrutura[1]).to have_select(options: ['CADASTRO TÉCNICO', 'D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA',...])` or possibly `expect(screen_grupo_intervencao.estrutura[1]).to match_selector(:select, options: ['CADASTRO TÉCNICO', 'D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA',...])` - I'm not 100% sure since I write Capybara but rarely use siteprism.  Pure capybara it would be `expect(page).to have_select('_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY', options: ['CADASTRO TÉCNICO', 'D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA',...])`. See Capybaras documentation for more info

Comment: Perfect its work fine!!! - expect(page).to have_select('_lyXWFMTGINID_ALAY', options: ["", "CADASTRO TÉCNICO", "D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA", "ENGENHARIA", "GESTÃO DE PERDAS", "GSC COMERCIAL", "GSO OPERACIONAL"]) .  As for this one I'm still trying expect(screen_grupo_intervencao.estrutura[1]).to have_select(options: ["", "CADASTRO TÉCNICO", "D&C - DISTRIBUIÇÃO E COLETA", "ENGENHARIA", "GESTÃO DE PERDAS", "GSC COMERCIAL", "GSO OPERACIONAL"])   error:  expected to find select box nil that is not disabled but there were no matches

Comment: @Tadeu As I said - wasn't 100% sure that was right, If the match_selector example also doesn't work, then check whether it should be `[1]` - I based that from your initial example, but Ruby starts arrays at `0` so if you're looking at the first item with that name then it should be `[0]`

Comment: I'm having a lot of problems with an application with many repeated ids. I asked the developer to put unique ids to make it easier for me but the guy doesn't help much.. Unfortunately this is Brazil